# How to stop console window from closing immediately | GNAT - GPS

Tags: ada, gnat-gps

I have Ada program that runs and compile perfectly using GNAT - GPS. When I run its exe file and provide user input then instead of saying "Press any key to continue", the exe closes immediately.

I have searched for it online alot but i only found info related to c/c++/visual studio console window using system('pause'); OR Console.Readline().

Is there any way around for this in Ada lanaguage?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apart from using `Get_Line` or `Get`, you can also use `Get_Immediate` from the [`Ada.Text_IO`](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-10-1.html) package. The difference is that `Get_Line` and `Get` will continue to read user input until `<Enter>` has been hit, while `Get_Immediate` will block only until a single key has been pressed when standard input is connected to an interactive device (e.g. a keyboard).

Here's an example:

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Main is
begin

   --  Do some interesting stuff here...   

   declare
      User_Response : Character;
   begin
      Put_Line ("Press any key to continue...");
      Get_Immediate (User_Response);
   end;

end Main;
```

*NOTES*

- You should run the program in an interactive terminal (Bash, PowerShell, etc.) to actually see the effect of `Get_Immediate`. When you run the program from within GPS, then you still have to press enter to actually exit the program.
- This might be too much detail, but I think that `Get` still waits for `<Enter>` to be pressed because it uses `fgetc` from the C standard library (libc) under the hood (see [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/gcc/ada/libgnat/a-textio.adb?view=markup#l503) and [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/gcc/ada/libgnat/a-textio.adb?view=markup#l849)). The function `fgetc` reads from a C stream. C streams are initially line-buffered for interactive devices ([source](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Buffering-Concepts.html#Buffering-Concepts)).

Comment: Worked Awesome! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The answer from @DeeDee is more portable and only Ada and the preferable way to go, so my answer is just if you are looking for a "windows" way to do it.

I think there is a linker option for it, but I couldn't find it.  A more manual way is to bind the system() command from C and give it a "pause" command and place it at the end of your program:

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Interfaces.C.Strings;

procedure Main is

   function System(Str : Interfaces.c.strings.chars_ptr) return Interfaces.C.int
      with Import,
      Convention => C,
      External_Name => "system";

   procedure Pause is
      Command : Interfaces.c.Strings.chars_ptr
         := Interfaces.C.Strings.New_String("pause");
      Result  : Interfaces.C.int
         := System(Command);
   begin
      Interfaces.C.Strings.Free(Command);
   end Pause;

begin
   Put_Line("Hello World");
   Pause;
end Main;
```

I know you mentioned seeing about pause already, but just wanted to show an example.

Answer (score 1):

The same way you could use `Console.Readline()`, you can use [`Get_Line`](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-A-10-7.html#p17.1) from the package [Ada.Text_IO](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-A-10-1.html).
In this case, you will have to put the result into a `String` that you won't use.